# in r, filter all groups that fulfill multiple conditions

Tags: r, sorting, dplyr, filter, grouping

This is an example from my df:

`df <- data.frame(species= c("dog", "dog", "dog", "cat", "cat", "fish", "fish"), percentage = c(12, 13, 19,  20, 12,  10, 50))`

I want to filter the df to include only species having at least two observations one with a percentage <13 AND  one observation >13. In that df, it will only be the dog (as dog has one observation of 11 and one observation of 19. Cat and fish have one observation below 11 but n).

I tried this:

`df %>% group_by(species) %>% filter(any(percentage < 13 & percentage >13))`

But I get an empty df...
Thanks!

Comment: You are trying to filter for a species which has at least one obs. with percentage < 13 and percentage > 13 at the same time. As this can't be true for one obs at the same time you get an empty dataset. Perhaps you want `filter(any(percentage < 13) & any(percentage > 13))`. However, note that for all three species you have obs with percentage < 13 and percentage > 13.

Answer (score 3):

I just assume that your example data is wrong, since, as stefan points out in the comments, "all three species you have obs with percentage < 13 and percentage > 13.".

If we change your example data, we can filter out dogs which is, now, the only species that has observations bigger and smaller than 13.

We can do this with a grouped filter using `any` (or alternatively `all` for other conditions).

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(species= c("dog", "dog", "dog", "cat", "cat", "fish", "fish"), percentage = c(12, 13, 19,  20, 16,  14, 50))

df
#>   species percentage
#> 1     dog         12
#> 2     dog         13
#> 3     dog         19
#> 4     cat         20
#> 5     cat         16
#> 6    fish         14
#> 7    fish         50

df %>% 
  group_by(species) %>% 
  filter(any(percentage > 13),
         any(percentage < 13))

#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#> # Groups:   species [1]
#>   species percentage
#>   <chr>        <dbl>
#> 1 dog             12
#> 2 dog             13
#> 3 dog             19
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Indeed, I made a mistake in the example df and I corrected it now for the record of the question. Your answer did the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

An alternative using some set theory, which should be markedly quicker in cases with a lot of groups:

```
## big example data
df <- data.frame(species= rep(1:3e6, rep(c(3,2,2), 1e6)),
                 percentage = c(12, 13, 19,  20, 16,  14, 50))
```

Intersection of `species` groups meeting both criteria:

```
system.time({
out1 <- df %>%
    filter(species %in% intersect(species[percentage > 13],
                                  species[percentage < 13]))
})
##   user  system elapsed 
##   0.61    0.10    0.70
```

Compared to:

```
system.time({
out2 <- df %>% 
    group_by(species) %>% 
    filter(any(percentage > 13),
           any(percentage < 13))
})
##   user  system elapsed 
##  14.59    0.46   15.04
```

Comparison checks out (minus tibble/data.frame conversion):

```
identical(out1, as.data.frame(out2))
##[1] TRUE
```